# Do uniform emitters look brighter from the edge?

Tags: optics, visible-light, radiation

Assuming we have a large flat object that emits photons equally from all points into all directions, does the object appear "brighter" when viewed from an angle (as opposed to straight down)? Here I define "brighter" to be energy received per unit area per time. I believe the brightness part of the question can be rephrased as "Would the pixels of a digital photograph corresponding to an angled photo of the object have higher value than those of a photograph corresponding to the straight-on angle?"

In the language of radiative transport, the question becomes: If the particles on the surface of an emitter are direction-agnostic, is $I_\nu(\theta)$ an increasing function of $\theta$, the angle between the surface normal and the direction of emission?

====

Here is my reasoning:

Take as true that a given particle on the surface of the object emits uniformly in the $\Omega = 2\pi$ half-sphere "above" the surface.

1. An object at a given temperature will radiate a finite amount of energy / time and with a given spectrum, so we can calculate photons/time.
2. Because the emission process is governed by QM, we can reasonably expect each atom is equally likely to emit as its neighbor.
3. The total number of photons emitted from the entire surface should be in a given direction should be independent of angle.
4. Therefore, the total number of photons passing through some differential area element $\mathrm{d}A$ a (perpendicular) distance $r$ away from emitter should be independent of angle. Then total energy passing through $\mathrm{d}A$ should be independent of angle.
5. More of an object is visible when it is viewed from an angle. Mathematically, the solid angle $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ corresponding a flat (e.g.) square decreases as you begin to look at the square from the edge.

Then the dependence of the quantity $I_\nu \sim \dfrac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}\nu \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}A \, \mathrm{d}\Omega}$ on angle is

$I_\nu(\theta) \sim \dfrac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}\nu \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}A \, \mathrm{d}\Omega(\theta)}$ where $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ decreases in $\theta$.

An interesting result of this is that the number of photons emitted from an isotropic spherical emitter is a function of angle.

====

Is this the correct result? It seems remarkably counterintuitive that a photograph of a uniform emitter would show the object as "brighter" from the edge, though maybe I'm just physically unfamiliar with "uniform emitters" as I defined them.

*Note this question isn't the same as "why do stars appear limb darkened", when atmospheres make a non-negligible appearance.*

Comment: Hopefully, someone who knows more will chime in, but I think that when one speaks of "isotropic" emitters (or diffuse reflectors) that what is usually meant is not a "direction agnostic" emitter like you've described but rather a "Lambertian" emitter in which the number of photons per solid angle is not constant but has a cos($\theta$) dependence, where $\theta$ is the angle between the normal to the surface and the emission direction. For a Lambertian emitter, one does see the same relative brightness (or luminance) regardless of how the surface is tilted. So it has "isotropic" brightness.

Comment: I agree that Lambertian emitters work "as expected", though for a smooth emitter, it's not clear (to me) why the law should hold. Shouldn't the emitting electron be unaware of the bulk shape?

Comment: Mark Eichenlaub [explains "A perfect blackbody must obey Lambert's law, or else it would break the second law of thermodynamics."](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-explain-Lamberts-cosine-law) I can't find any derivation at the atomic level.